# Visual Studio 2015 runs aapt.exe process uses 100% usage of CPU

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cpu-usage, nuget-package

I am using visual studio 2015 update 2 community version to build Xamarin Applications. When I add a new nuget package or update my existing packages the aapt.exe process turns on which uses 100% of the CPU. It keeps me waiting for ages to complete the nuget package installation. Any one facing the same problem. Solutions to this are highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get rid of this problem?

Comment: No I haven't got any solution about it. This occurs when I install multiple packages at once. I don't do that now I install one at a time. @RoarG

Answer (score 9):

Open your Android project file in your text editor of choice and add the following to the main PropertyGroup, Debug configuration:

```
<AndroidResgenExtraArgs>--no-crunch</AndroidResgenExtraArgs>
```

The  the aapt.exe process is trying to crunch (process) all of your image (png) files whenever you add a new nuget package or component.

Comment: Getting: error : Unknown option '--no-crunch--no-version-vectors'

Comment: @RoarG try `<AndroidResgenExtraArgs>--no-crunch </AndroidResgenExtraArgs>` (notice the trailing space)

Comment: This worked for me, so far (with the trailing space).

Comment: Worked for me, too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in a text editor and add:

```
<AndroidExplicitCrunch>true</AndroidExplicitCrunch>
```

to the property group for the debug configuration(s).

This will make the build system cache the files generated by aapt so that in future it will only be run on files which have changed. The first build after adding this will still be really slow while the cache is built, but subsequent builds should be much faster. This should also be true for runs of aapt triggered by changing resource files etc. they should also use the cache and be faster.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52967

The problem related to how AAPT handles V7 compatibility component. Hope they will fix it for VS since we don't experience such behavior with Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with apt too

Which package you are trying to poll or update?

make sure get the lastest Android SDK package and build toos everyday

and dont install this 2 package

[image]

Comment: I don't have them installed.

Comment: U need rest of them for the support, the problem is MS:Built .

Comment: I have other's installed. I was talking about the arrows shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53817

"Fixed by Xamarin.Build.Download 0.4.3-beta2 and higher"